# How to remove everything after the third two backward slashes in Python

Tags: python, string, path

I have the following string:

```
'C:\\Research\\Dataset\\ABC\\DEF\\GHI\\000000_P0000\\1.jpg.npy'
```

I wish to only print the following from it:

```
'C:\\Research\\Dataset\\ABC\\DEF\\GHI\\000000_P0000'
```

I have tried rsplit but it separates folder

Comment: Use `pathlib` to parse it, then get the directory portion.

Comment: Or use the older `os.path.dirname()` function.

Comment: As a general recommendation, don't handle paths as strings. Use proper path objects from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). See esp. [`Path.parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent)

Comment: Your title and content do not match.